# HTML page is not showing the info I need from json file

Tags: javascript, html, json

*My script, this should be showing the Name of game computers in html but it does not, I have been trying so much andI betit will just be something stupid that is wrong or missing*
**Console says : TypeError: data is undefined**

#### The console does show me retrieving the data works

```
"use strict";

window.addEventListener("load", Init);

function Init() {
  fetch("https://howest-gp-wfa.github.io/st-2021-1-S2-a-wfa-pe03-Jonas-Bundervoet/api/products.json")
  .then(function(response) { return response.json();  })
  .then(data => console.log(data))
  .then(function(data){
    tester(data)
  })
  .catch(err => console.log(err));

 window.addEventListener("load", tester);
}
```

**My function to show data on screen (shows nothing)**

```
function tester(data)
{
  let div = document.getElementById("test");

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    let article = document.createElement("h1");
    article.innerHTML = 'Name: ' + data.GameComputers[0].Name;
    div.appendChild(article);
  };
}
```

**In HTML I just have this in my body**
`<div id="test"></div>`

Comment: (Could you maybe not format ALL the text in bold ALL the time? I see you doing that in previous questions as well. The point of formatting is to put emphasis on specific parts, but just using it for everything from start to finish, makes that kinda moot to begin with.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## console.log returns undefined

> ```
> .then(data => console.log(data))
> .then(function(data){
>           tester(data)
> ```

Your first `then` returns the return value of `console.log` which is `undefined`.

So your second `then` recieves `undefined` as its `data`.

Don't use multiple `then` callbacks here.

```
 .then(function(data){
           console.log(data)
           tester(data)
```

## The JSON doesn't consist of an array

The JSON you are looking at returns an object.

It doesn't have a `length`.

> ```
> for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
> ```

… is going to fail immediately.

You've got `data.GameComputers[0]` so I'm guessing you want to loop over `GameComputers` so:

1. Check the length of that: `i < data.GameComputers.length`
2. Make use of `i` when you read it: `data.GameComputers[i].Name;`

Comment: So I should put `i < data.GameComputers.length`in the for ()? Or what is it that u mean